# in search of libraries for visual studios 2013, where & how to obtain

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

i have found some source file online and the individual responsible for it hasn't reply back, i need to know how does one go about finding this particular libraries if one was to need in the near future?

in processing its easy you just go to the library download manager and type the name of that library.

is there a way to do this in Visual studios?

below you can see what i think i need to fix my issue.

```
#include<opencv/cvaux.h>// in need of it 
#include<opencv/cxcore.h>//in need of it
```

this is why i think i need those files above,

> ERRORS:
>   Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseMemStorage
>   referenced in function
>   main
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvInRangeS
>   referenced in function
>   main
>
> Error 5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvGetSeqElem
>   referenced in function
>   main
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateMemStorage
>   referenced in function
>   main
>
> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage
>   referenced in function
>   main
>
> Error 6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCircle referenced
>   in function
>   main
>
> Error 7   error LNK1120: 6 unresolved
>   externals

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateMemStorage referenced in function main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseMemStorage referenced in function main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvGetSeqElem referenced in function main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCircle referenced in function main
```

the funny thing is that there's no squiggly red lines in the code telling me that this! is whats wrong, this is why im guessing that the problem is cuz of the lacking of those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starting the development process using libraries like OpenCV or OpenGL,you need to install some packages and do a bunch of configurations on your Visual Studio.From [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.1.0/opencv-3.1.0.exe/download) you can download the missing packages for windows,you can also have a [Quick start](http://opencv.org/quickstart.html) on the website which will get you on the path for beginning,to be more specific [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) is a complete guide of building OpenCV apps inside Visual Studio